# Netty IdleStateHandler times out for large messages

Tags: java, netty

I'm using Netty's IdleStateHandler in my client/server communication to send heartbeats (server to client) and detect timeouts on the client. This works fine expect for rare cases when the transfer of large messages takes longer than the configured read timeout.
I my case these large messages only happen at the client's startup (baseline), during normal operation the messages are small, hence I'm reluctant to increase the overall read timeout on the client.

Is there a way for prevent the IdleStateHandler from firing idle state events while it's actually receiving data? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `IdleStateHandler` as first handler to the 'ChannelPipeline' solved my problem. This ensures the timestamp of the last received data is updated as often as possible.